# What truly happens when you try to npm install specific package?

Tags: node.js, npm

Here is what's given:

- part of the packages from project dependencies are located in the private registry. They're completely independent;
- correctly-filled package-lock.json left from the previous npm install;
- empty node_modules folder;

Now, when I run `npm install <package-name>` (package already listed in package.json and package-lock.json) npm tries to restore all packages listed on the lock file, stumbles on private packages, and fails to install one specific package because of an authorization error that unrelated to it.
With the `--no-shrinkwrap` option or with filled node_modules everything working as expected.
I first thought that it connected with the audit, but --no-audit option didn't change anything.

My question is, why npm behaves like this when there are no visible (at least for me) reasons for it?

npm version: 6.9.0 but I also was able to reproduce it on the latest version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, as usual, was in the docs. According to the https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-install#algorithm npm takes `package.json`, adds requested dependency, and then tries to restore everything that is missing in comparison with the existing node_modules tree.

The other part of the doc says that if `package-lock.json` exists npm install uses it by default. So in the result, we get an empty node_modules, hence no tree exists but package-lock claims that there should be packages and we ends up restoring all dependency tree for nothing.

If we omit usage of `package-lock.json` the only difference between expected and actual tree will be the package we were trying to install.